# How to extract a particular word from a content using python

Tags: python

I am new to python and i am trying to extract particular word from the content below starting with letter B and its following 10 characters. Example as shown below.

"FnSku/X-label from the item:na

Incorrect value:**BXXXXXXXXA**

Correct (if available):na

Condition of the part(Used/New?): new

Purchase order:na"

I am looking to extract the word BXXXXXXXXA. I tried to split the content and find the word that startswith 'B' however since word does not start with B i am unable to extract the same.

Note: the content is not always the same but the count of letter starting with B is always 10.

Please help !

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with regular expression:

```
import re

 Words_starting_by_B= re.findall("B\w{9}", text)
```

Comment: i tried the below and got the output as follows

def getWords(sentence, letter):
    regex = r'\b(#\w*[^#\W]|[^#\W]\w*#)\b'.replace('#', letter)
    return re.findall(regex, sentence, re.I)


['BXXXXXXXXA', 'being', 'Bin']